# jQuery Autocomplete for a JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My JSON is like this

```
var data = [{"code":"1162","format":"Subscription","name":"Picture Manager ","action":"202"},
{"code" : "1094","format":"Store","name":"Listing Designer","action":"168"},
{"code" : "1407","format":"Subscription","name":"MOTOR_PACKAGE","action":"403"},
{"code" : "1024","format":"Fixed Price","Name":"Picture","action":"120"},
{"code" : "1051","format":"Auction","name":"Gallery Days","action":"49"},
{"code" : "5059","format":"Lead Generation","name":"Scheduled Listings","action":"160"}];
```

I am able to create a suggest function like

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    serverurl = "getJson";
    $.getJSON( serverurl, function(data) {
        $("#feeCode").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                response($.map(data, function(v,i){
                    return {
                             label: v.format+' / '+v.name+' ('+v.code+')' ,
                             value: v.format+' / '+v.name+' ('+v.code+')'
                    };
                }));
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input class="catinputbox" type="text" id="feeCode" >
```

It will show the suggestion like this

```
Auction / Gallery Days (1051)
Fixed Price / Picture (1024)
```

But it is not searching the pattern the suggestions are static. I want to search and give the appropriate suggestion for the string he is providing. Like if he types "Fixed" the suggestion should be "Fixed Price / Picture (1024)" or if he types "Days" or "1051" then "Auction / Gallery Days (1051)".

I have never used the autocomplete before so if any one can explain me autocomplete, request, response and search. That will be very helpful for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, just a few tweaks:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    serverurl = "getJson";

    $.getJSON(serverurl, function(data) {
       /* When the response comes back, create an array of objects that the 
        * autocomplete widget can use, using `$.map`:
        */
        var autocompleteData = $.map(data, function(v, i) {
            return {
                label: v.format+' / '+v.name+' ('+v.code+')' ,
                value: v.format+' / '+v.name+' ('+v.code+')'
            };
        });

        /* Initialize the autocomplete widget with the prepared data: */
        $("#feeCode").autocomplete({
            source: autocompleteData
        });
    }); 
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/fny66zkd/

In this case, you don't need to supply a function to the `source` parameter. You do this if you want to perform a custom AJAX request or some other type of custom filtering function.

Your code wasn't working before because when you supply a function to the `source` parameter, you're essentially telling the widget that *you* want to do the filtering.

> I have never used the autocomplete before so if any one can explain me autocomplete, request, response and search. That will be very helpful for me

- The `source` option can be supplied a callback function (or a string, or an array). This function accepts two parameters, `request` and `response`.

  - `request` is an object containing information about what the user typed. You can access what they typed by accessing `request.term`.
  - `response` is a callback function that jQueryUI passes your function. You call this function when you're ready to notify the widget of a resultset you want to show the user.
  - More information is available in the [official documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).
- The `search` method manually invokes the autocomplete widget's searching functionality. Again, more information is available in the [official documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search).

Comment: can you tell me how to do the validation as well

Comment: @Shivay: What validation do you mean?

Comment: that the input term in the text box is from that map. can we do it in auto complete function or i have to right another function for that.

Comment: You would have to tap into the `change` event. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/fny66zkd/1/

Comment: Hi, @AndrewWhitaker, nice answer - i am using the same code of yours but i need little tweek in this. on click of BackSpace Button again reg(g) global match has to happen which is not happening - please have a look at this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860753/jquery-filter-function-is-not-working-on-backspace-trigger -----   DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/hb2zamrh/1/