# on Click of Backspace Button jQuery Filter is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/hb2zamrh/1/)**

hi all, 
i have developed an Filtration based on JSON Data, when i type in text box Works Fine (Searches Perfect), but when i press Back Button (e.keyCode == 8) Iam Resetting all the Data.

- scenario :

  if the User has typed (**J**) 2 results are displaying which is expected, if the user want to change name by some other word by pressing back button only 2 Results has to be Displayed instead of all the data.

**JS :**

```
$(function(){
            var data = {
                "users": [
                            {
                                "id"        : 01,
                                "docName"   : "Dwayne Johnson",
                                "docCat"    : "Neurologist",
                                "docPic"    : "url('../images/01.png')"
                            },
                            {
                                "id"        : 02,
                                "docName"   : "Vin Diesel",
                                "docCat"    : "Skin Specialist",
                                "docPic"    : "url('../images/02.png')"
                            },
                            {
                                "id"        : 03,
                                "docName"   : "Paul Walker",
                                "docCat"    : "Specialist",
                                "docPic"    : "url('../images/03.png')"
                            },
                            {
                                "id"        : 04,
                                "docName"   : "Jason Statham",
                                "docCat"    : "Actor",
                                "docPic"    : "url('../images/01.png')"
                            },
                            {
                                "id"        : 05,
                                "docName"   : "Michelle Rodriguez",
                                "docCat"    : "Actress",
                                "docPic"    : "url('../images/01.png')"
                            }
                        ]
            }

            $(data.users).each(function () {
                var output = 
                    "<li>" + 
                        this.docName + " / " + 
                        this.docCat + " / " + 
                        this.docPic
                    "</li>";
                $('#placeholder ul').append(output);
            });

            $('#search-doctor').keyup(function () {
                var doctorVal = $(this).val();
                if (doctorVal.length > 0) {
                    var filterDoctor = 
                        $("li").filter(function () {
                            var str = $(this).text();
                            var re = new RegExp(doctorVal, "i");
                            var result = re.test(str);
                            if (!result) {
                                return $(this);
                            }
                    }).hide();
                    $(this).keyup(function(e){
                        if(e.keyCode == 8) {
                            $("li").show();
                        }
                    })
                } 
                else {
                    $("li").show();
                }
            });
        })
```

**html :**

```
<input type="search" name="search" id="search-doctor" value="" />
    <div id="placeholder"><ul></ul></div>
```

Comment: Don't bind event handlers within event handlers, this is (almost) always an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do:

*"Show or hide each `<li>`, depending on whether their text matches an input value."*

Let's just write that down:

```
$("#placeholder li").each(function () {
    var isMatch = $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(searchStr) > -1;
    $(this)[isMatch ? "show" : "hide"]();
});
```

or, in context (expand code snippet to run):

```js
var data = {
    "users": [
        {
            "id"        : 01,
            "docName"   : "Dwayne Johnson",
            "docCat"    : "Neurologist",
            "docPic"    : "url('../images/01.png')"
        },
        {
            "id"        : 02,
            "docName"   : "Vin Diesel",
            "docCat"    : "Skin Specialist",
            "docPic"    : "url('../images/02.png')"
        },
        {
            "id"        : 03,
            "docName"   : "Paul Walker",
            "docCat"    : "Specialist",
            "docPic"    : "url('../images/03.png')"
        },
        {
            "id"        : 04,
            "docName"   : "Jason Statham",
            "docCat"    : "Actor",
            "docPic"    : "url('../images/01.png')"
        },
        {
            "id"        : 05,
            "docName"   : "Michelle Rodriguez",
            "docCat"    : "Actress",
            "docPic"    : "url('../images/01.png')"
        }
    ]
};

$(function(){
    $.each(data.users, function (i, user) {
        var str = [user.docName, user.docCat, user.docPic].join('/');
        $("<li>", {text: str}).appendTo('#placeholder ul');
    });

    $('#search-doctor').keyup(function () {
        var searchStr = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
        
        $("#placeholder li").each(function () {
            var isMatch = $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(searchStr) > -1;
            $(this)[isMatch ? "show" : "hide"]();
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="search" name="search" id="search-doctor" value="" />
<div id="placeholder"><ul></ul></div>
```

Notes:

- Never nest event handlers inside other event handlers, like you did with `keyup`. If you press 10 keys, your code will create 10 new keyup handlers, this is certainly not what you had in mind.
- Use regex for pattern searches. Avoid it for simple substring matches that can easily be accomplished by `indexOf`.

Comment: Wow Thanks a lot :-)